# Inserir dados de um TXT em um DB

Tags: mysql, delphi

Mesmo fazendo todas essas condições, o meu banco de dados esta respondendo de forma estranha, pois literalmente o que estou selecionando, está em cada linha do meu arquivo *.txt*, retorna tudo, inclusive os espaços vazios, o que não era para ocorrer.

Segue o código:

```pascal
//while para ler o txt e definir as variáveis.
  AssignFile(txt, edtCaminho.Text);
  Reset(txt);
  while not eof(txt) do
  begin
    Readln(txt, lTemp);
    inc(i);
    with DataModule1.ZQuery1 do
    begin
      if (copy(lTemp, 23, 3) = 'GNF') and (copy(lTemp, 39, 3) = 'COO') then
      begin
        gnf := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'CDC' then
      begin
        cdc := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 14, 22) = 'NÃO É DOCUMENTO FISCAL' then
      begin
        ndocf := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 10, 29) = 'COMPROVANTE CRÉDITO OU DÉBITO' then
      begin
        comp := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 22, 6) = 'CARTÃO' then
      begin
        cartao := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 24, 3) = 'VIA' then
      begin
        via := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'COO' then
      begin
        coo := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 1, 15) = 'Valor da compra' then
      begin
        vlcompra := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 1, 18) = 'Valor do pagamento' then
      begin
        vlpag := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 18, 4) = 'REDE' then
      begin
        rede := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if (copy(lTemp, 14, 13) = 'VISA ELECTRON') or (copy(lTemp, 17, 7) = 'MAESTRO') then
      begin
        band := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 1, 7) = 'COMPROV' then
      begin
        comprov := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 1, 5) = 'ESTAB' then
      begin
        estab := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 19, 4) = 'TERM' then
      begin
        term := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 1, 15) = 'NUMERO PARCELAS' then
      begin
        numparc := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 1, 6) = 'CARTAO' then
      begin
        cartao2 := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 1, 11) = 'AUTORIZACAO' then
      begin
        auto := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 1, 4) = 'ARQC' then
      begin
        arqc := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 5, 29) = 'TRANSACAO AUTORIZADA MEDIANTE' then
      begin
        trans := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 5, 20) = 'USO DE SENHA PESSOAL' then
      begin
        usodesp := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = '---' then
      begin
        traco := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 1, 8) = 'BEMATECH' then
      begin
        imp := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 1, 6) = 'VERSÃO' then
      begin
        versao := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'QQQ' then
      begin
        qqq := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;
      if copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'FAB' then
      begin
        fab := copy(lTemp, 1, 48);
      end;

      DataModule1.Zquery1.Close;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO lercartao(lgnf, lcdc, lndocf, lcomp, lcartao, lvia, lcoo, lvlcompra, lvlpag, lrede, lband, lcomprov, lestab, lterm, lnumparc, lcartao2, lauto, larqc, lusodesp, ltraco, limp, lversao, lqqq, lfab)');
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('VALUES (:pgnf, :pcdc, :pndocf, :pcomp, :pcartao, :pvia, :pcoo, :pvlcompra, :pvlpag, :prede, :pband, :pcomprov, :pestab, :pterm, :pnumparc, :pcartao2, :pauto, :parqc, :pusodesp, :ptraco, :pimp, :pversao, :pqqq, :pfab)');
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pgnf').AsString := gnf;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pcdc').AsString := cdc;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pndocf').AsString := ndocf;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pcomp').AsString := comp;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pcartao').AsString := cartao;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pvia').AsString := via;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pcoo').AsString := coo;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pvlcompra').AsString := vlcompra;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pvlpag').AsString := vlpag;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('prede').AsString := rede;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pband').AsString := band;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pcomprov').AsString := comprov;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pestab').AsString := estab;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pterm').AsString := term;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pnumparc').AsString := numparc;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pcartao2').AsString := cartao2;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pauto').AsString := auto;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('parqc').AsString := arqc;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pusodesp').AsString := usodesp;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('ptraco').AsString := traco;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pimp').AsString := imp;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pversao').AsString := versao;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pqqq').AsString := qqq;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pfab').AsString := fab;
      DataModule1.ZQuery1.ExecSQL;
    end;
  end;
  CloseQuery;
  Closefile(txt);
  //relatório query
  DataModule1.ZQuery2.Close;
  DataModule1.ZQuery2.SQL.Clear;
  DataModule1.ZQuery2.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM lercartao LIMIT 0, '+ IntToStr(i));
  DataModule1.ZQuery2.Open;
```

Porém, quando ele insere os dados no meu bando de dados, ele me aparece isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E segue por mais 255 registros, como cascata, mostrando cada linha que o `while` percorreu, como se estivesse percorrendo apenas até a minha condição e retornando o `while`.

Por que? Poderia ser um problema no meu Insert? ou poderia ser um problema com o meu código? Alguma ideia?

**Atualização**

```
           xxxxxxxxxxxx
          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
 PCA. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, CENTRO MOSSORO-RN
CNPJ:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
IE:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        
------------------------------------------------
05/12/2013 17:34:07   GNF:xxxxxx      COO:xxxxxx
CDC:0006
             NÃO É DOCUMENTO FISCAL             
         COMPROVANTE CRÉDITO OU DÉBITO          
                     CARTAO                     
                     1ªVIA                      
COO do documento vinculado:               xxxxxx
Valor da compra  R$                        63,35
Valor do pagamento  R$                     63,35
                 REDE                           
              MASTERCARD                        
COMPR:xxxxxxxx4    VALOR:        63,35          
ESTAB:xxxxxxxxx PLASTIJxxxxx                    
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx TERM:PV834358/050075          
NUMERO PARCELAS : 02                            
CARTAO: xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx                     
AUTORIZACAO: xxxxxx                             
ARQC:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                          
    TRANSACAO AUTORIZADA MEDIANTE               
    USO DE SENHA PESSOAL.                       

                               (SiTef)          

------------------------------------------------
BEMATECH xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
VERSÃO:xxxxxxxx ECF:xxx LJ:xxxx
QQQQQQQQQxxxxxxx 05/12/2013 17:34:13 
FAB:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Segue o texto do arquivo, como solicitado.

O `X` e substituição pois há informações *pessoais* da empresa, mas é estilo isto. Caso haja alguma duvida só falar.

Comment: Posta um pedaço do txt, umas 5 linhas bastam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duas dúvidas surgiram:

1. Pra que o `inc(i)`?
2. Como seu código compilou com `with DataModule1.ZQuery1 do`?

---

Mas voltando à sua pergunta:

### Por que não funciona?

O seu TXT não está formatado conforme o que você programou. Para seu código funcionar, todas as informações devem estar na mesma linha.

A cada ReadLN um grupo de variáveis é preenchido, chegando ao ponto em que todas elas estão e finalmente você tem um registro completo.

Uma forma fácil de contornar o erro de lógica seria antes de preencher o ZQuery1 verificar se todas as variáveis estão preenchidas e logo após apagar todas elas.

Simplificando muito, algo mais ou menos assim:

```delphi
If (trim(gnf) <> '') and (trim(cdc) <> '') ... then  //todas as outras variáveis
begin
  DataModule1.Zquery1.Close;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO lercartao(lgnf, lcdc, lndocf, lcomp, lcartao, lvia, lcoo, lvlcompra, lvlpag, lrede, lband, lcomprov, lestab, lterm, lnumparc, lcartao2, lauto, larqc, lusodesp, ltraco, limp, lversao, lqqq, lfab)');
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('VALUES (:pgnf, :pcdc, :pndocf, :pcomp, :pcartao, :pvia, :pcoo, :pvlcompra, :pvlpag, :prede, :pband, :pcomprov, :pestab, :pterm, :pnumparc, :pcartao2, :pauto, :parqc, :pusodesp, :ptraco, :pimp, :pversao, :pqqq, :pfab)');
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pgnf').AsString := gnf;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pcdc').AsString := cdc;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pndocf').AsString := ndocf;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pcomp').AsString := comp;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pcartao').AsString := cartao;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pvia').AsString := via;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pcoo').AsString := coo;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pvlcompra').AsString := vlcompra;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pvlpag').AsString := vlpag;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('prede').AsString := rede;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pband').AsString := band;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pcomprov').AsString := comprov;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pestab').AsString := estab;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pterm').AsString := term;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pnumparc').AsString := numparc;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pcartao2').AsString := cartao2;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pauto').AsString := auto;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('parqc').AsString := arqc;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pusodesp').AsString := usodesp;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('ptraco').AsString := traco;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pimp').AsString := imp;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pversao').AsString := versao;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pqqq').AsString := qqq;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ParamByName('pfab').AsString := fab;
  DataModule1.ZQuery1.ExecSQL;
  gnf := '';
  cdc := '';
  //Todas as outras variáveis
end;
```

Dessa forma você contorna o erro e obtém o resultado esperado.

Comment: O `i`, eh para contar os registros inseridos me mostrar em um select e o  `with` foi apenas um teste que fiz...

Comment: O problema  eh que nao estará as informacoes em uma linha , eu fiz o codigo para srmazerar a linha toda em um blob e no select ele me mostrar, eu consegui aazenar , o unico problema eh o dessa img... a que postei...

Comment: O erro maior nem foi de programação, mas de lógica. Dá uma olhada no edit.

Comment: Tntei fzer o que disse, mas ele nao pega nada , fica vazio o banco, compilou o codigo direitinho, mas tipo, a logica nao estaria eerrada , eh a penas a forma de fazer com que cada linha do txtarmazene em um field no db...

Comment: Cada `ReadLN` vai pegar uma parte da informação que você precisa. O bloco só está completo no último `ReadLN` do bloco, troque meu if por `if copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'FAB' then`

Comment: E aqueles ifs que fiz, ficam obsoletos? `if (copy(lTemp, 23, 3) = 'GNF') and (copy(lTemp, 39, 3) = 'COO') ` por exemplo...

Comment: Não, só substitui o único if do meu bloco pelo que postei no comentario.

Comment: Meu amiiiiiigo deu certo !!!! Obrigadoooo!!!

Comment: Sempre que compilar direito e aparecer algum erro desse tipo, pense na lógica. O que costumo fazer é pegar papel e caneta pra ver se a solução funciona mesmo.

Comment: beleza cara, vou adotar essa nesma ideia para mim, muito obrigado